# The limit of Facebook's graph api "limit" parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm fetching a large amount of comments from a public page using Facebook's Graph API.
By default facebook returns 25 comments per response, and uses paging. This causes the need for multiple requests, which is uneccesery as I know ahead there will be  a lot of comments.

I read about the "limit" parameter that you can pass to ask for a certain amount of items per response.

I was wondering, what is the limit of that parameter? I'm assuming I can't pass &limit=10000.

Comment: The maximum limit value depends on the object. Most seem to have an internal limit in the 250-500 range, but I've found a few that will return up to 5000 items.  There's no documentation, so you'll just have to keep bumping up the value until you stop getting more data.

Comment: "Some edges may also have a maximum on the limit value for performance reasons." - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Comment: I wonder if anyone reading this old question about the FB API "limit" param could also answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57454155/470749

Answer (score 13):

There's a different way for fetching comments:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>_<POST_ID>/comments?limit=500
```

The maximum value for the limit parameter is 500.

Comment: UPDATE: The limit now appears to be 100

Comment: @ChrisHoughton source?

Comment: As of 8/12/16 I'm still getting 500 results when listing all members in a group

Comment: I think limit is different according to the end point you are calling. for example in user likes is it 100 while it is 500 in public pages videos

Comment: Yes think it's object specific. I tried to get users attending an event having 1900 attendees and could get to `limit=2000` to get them all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876105/the-limit-of-facebooks-graph-api-limit-parameter#comment98271753_14876105

Answer (score 9):

yes, with limit parameter you can pass what number of certain resource you want in one call. default limit is 25.

for ex. if you want 100 comment in one call for a post having id `POST_ID`, you can query like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=comments.limit(100)
```

Comment: What is the difference between specifying a global "limit" parameter and specifying the limit for a certain field?

Comment: what do you mean by global limit?

Comment: The difference between https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=comments.limit(100) and https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=comments&limit=100

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=comments&limit=100 query doesn't make any sense. this is going to return default 25 comments for the given post `POST_ID`. but if you do query like https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?limit=10, it will return your first 10 posts.

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused :) what is the difference between limiting the field ( like when we did comments.limit(100) ) and limiting the amount of items themselves ( like when we did posts?limit=10 )

Comment: `?limit=10` is for the requested object, `.limit(10)` for the included field: `/me/posts?limit=10&fields=comments.limit(50)` = "give me 10 posts with 50 comments each"

Answer (score 1):

I think they have changed this. For /feed? I only get 200-225 posts back but for comments I get as many as 2000 back

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this is in the current Facebook documentation in case anyone finds this question via search (emphasis mine):

> Some edges may also have a maximum on the limit value for performance reasons. **In all cases, the API returns the correct pagination links.**

In other words, even if you specify a limit above what's allowed by the endpoint, the "pagination.previous" and "pagination.next" elements will always provide the correct URL to resume where it left off.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use FQL instead.

FQL provide a more flexible approach where you can combine data types (posts, users, pages, etc..) as you please. You can also query for comments belonging to a list of stories instead of just one limiting your number of requests even more.

There are a couple of drawbacks though:

1. There is a limit on 5000 comments. Here you would use a query looking something like: "SELECT id, ...... FROM comments, ... WHERE parent_id in (1,2,3....) ORDER BY time LIMIT 0, 5000". Even though you split this up in several queries with "LIMIT 0, 1000", "LIMIT 1000, 1000", LIMIT 2000, 1000, etc.., you would never get anything over 5000 comments("LIMIT 5000, 1000" would return empty).

2. All real requests made on Facebooks server counts as one request. You can send of something that is actually a combination of requests, this will be counted as multiple requests.

3. Facebook does not like to heavy requests. You can end up with getting blocked for a shorter time periods(minutes -> hours, not days). If this happens, act on it.

Comment: FQL is deprecated now. Versions after v2.0 will not support it anymore.