# Graph API stalled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that uses the Graph API to read a feed from the Facebook group:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/1396648167216137/

Neither my app nor the Graph API Explorer on the Facebook developers home pages return any posts later than the 16th October 2013 yet later posts are clearly visible on the group page.

Any suggestions as to how to get the latest posts greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow this up.  Turns out the 16th was purely coincidental, no posts or comments had been made except for comments on a particular post.  What I was actually running into was the comment paging.  Solved by adding &comments.limit=100 to the end of the URL.  Answer obtained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876105/the-limit-of-facebooks-graph-api-limit-parameter)

Kind Regards,

Rob